# Getting a simple timestamp from the FullCalendar event object

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I already got my FullCalendar feeds working well by defining an eventSource.

```
eventSources: [
{
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: svcURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),
                sid: %sid%,
                csrf_test_name: csrf
            },
            success: function(json) {
                callback(json);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I got my timestamps perfect by copying and pasting from the examples. However, I have another ajax function with which I want to use timestamps as well, but instead of timestamps I'm getting a text version of the data:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    if (confirm('Quer mesmo marcar este serviço?')){
        markit(event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The eventClick function passes the event object to my "markit" function:

```
function markit(obj){
    $.ajax({
        url: msvURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            start: obj.start,
            end: obj.end,
            sid: obj.sid,
            uid: obj.uid,
            aid: obj.aid,
            csrf_test_name: csrf
        },
        success: function(json) {
            alert('Got it marked!')
        }
    });
}
```

As I said, the markit function doesn't pass a timestamp for 'start' and 'end' so the data is harder to work with. How can I convert the times to timestamps?

UPDATE: The text version that is being sent is as follows:

```
Tue Mar 19 2013 09:30:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

Although I can parse that with PHP, life would be much simpler if I could work with timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works, but I changed the start and end values to the following and I get the timestamp I was looking for:

```
function markit(obj){
    $.ajax({
        url: msvURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            start: Math.round(obj.start / 1000),
            end: Math.round(obj.end / 1000),
            sid: obj.sid,
            uid: obj.uid,
            aid: obj.aid,
            csrf_test_name: csrf
        },
        success: function(json) {
            obj.aid = json;
            alert('Got it marked! AID: ' + json)
        }
    });
}
```

It doesn't make sense to me how I can use math functions on something that isn't a numerical value. If someone can leave a comment to explain that, I'd appreciate it.